# SQL speed increase: Left Join, or Cartesian product/where clause

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I'm working with a sql query in a webservice and am looking to increase its speed. As of now, the query takes the cartesian products of multiple tables and uses a where clause to separate them out.

I was wondering if switching to a LEFT JOIN would make the query execute faster since every row I want in my result is based off of one table, with additional information being pulled in from others.

Comment: as a good rule of thumb it is best to join tables how mysql intended it to be joined... aka don't do the cartesian product... join tables with JOIN filter data with WHERE... that aside there isn't much difference speed wise when doing one or the other. you should look at adding indexes to your tables

Comment: Can you post your query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to express the intent of a `LEFT JOIN` in MySQL using Cartesian syntax.

In Oracle, this so-called omega-join syntax

```
SELECT whatever FROM A, B WHERE A.col=B.col(+)
```

is equivalent to this:

```
SELECT whatever FROM A LEFT JOIN B ON A.col=B.col
```

But in MySQL only the latter syntax works. So if you want to do true `LEFT JOIN` operations in MySQL you have no choice: the cartesian/WHERE syntax doesn't work.

As far as optimization goes, MySQL's query execution planner does a pretty good job of understanding ordinary `INNER JOIN` operations expressed in cartesian/WHERE syntax. But you're almost always better off using the JOIN syntax. It's easier to read, and the query planner understands it.